# how to remove anything after youtube id using mysql?

Tags: mysql, url, youtube

Hello guys I have a mysql table with a column named ae_url which has youtube urls in it, and I would like to remove anything after the youtube id. For example:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1B6tWkbso1o&feature=youtu.be
remove "&feature=youtu.be"

There are some cases when a playlist comes after youtube id as well.

How can I accomplish this task using mysql queries ?
I have to update the column ae_url which contains thousand of youtube urls by removing anything anything after youtube id

Thank you so much for your kind assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

It'll pretty much fall to you to identify if there's any consistent identifier for when the youtube ID ends.

Two main options would be:

1) Identify when a non-id character comes into play (in this case "&") and truncate the entries

2) See if the number of characters in ID is consistent

For example 1, lets assume the indicator is the "&" character

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN trunc_url string;
UPDATE your_table SET trunc_url = 
     substring(ae_url, 1, --Start from first character
     charindex("&",ae_url)-1) --Index end by wherever the "&" symbol is found for cutting off;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
update tbl set ae_url = substr(ae_url, 1, locate('&', ae_url) - 1) 
where locate('&', ae_url) > 0
```

?

Comment: This removed almost all of my youtube urls (the good news is that I am always working on copies first)

Comment: Looks like some of them did not have & in them. Try the updated answer (on a copy first, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution:
UPDATE videos SET ae_url = LEFT(ae_url, LOCATE('&', ae_url) - 1) WHERE ae_url like '%&%';

It worked brilliantly

Thanks for your kind suggestions as well